# How to open keyboard settings Activity programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing a custom keyboard app. I have created my custom keyboard settings screen using a `PreferenceActivity`. I want to include "Auto correct", "Auto Capitalize Word" and "Vibrate" options in my custom keyboard settings section. All these options are available for the default Android keyboard. Please suggest any tutorials or reference links for achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement those settings on your own. 
`Auto Capitalize Word` and `Vibrate` are easy to implement with just a couple method overrides (for example you could override [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) method and when the the method is called you can send a small [vibration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) if the user has set the Vibrate option to true). Auto capitalize can also be achieved via [various ways](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_touppercase.htm).

Now the Auto Correct function is a little trickier to implement than the first two. First of all you will need a vocabulary of which to draw your suggestions on AutoCorrect and several other things that depend on your implementation. [This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) is an example of a ready view that you could possibly subclass to achieve something different if you wish.

Finally the most important part that might interest you is [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2012/08/creating-your-own-spelling-checker.html) blog entry.